# the_content filter to add custom fields to JSON response

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am little desesperate with this `the_content` filter for display custom field in JSON API.

I am using this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ to have JSON response from my custom post types. These custom post types have custom fields that I have to show in a mobile app.

To implement this I wrote this code, that use `the_content filter` to replace the original content to only show the custom post type with HTML tags:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_custom_post_fields_to_the_content' );

function add_custom_post_fields_to_the_content( $content ){

    global $post;

    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    $content = '<img id="provider-logo" src="'.$custom_fields["wpcf-logo"][0].'" />';
    $content = $content.'<img id="provider-image" src="'.$custom_fields["wpcf-fotos"][0].'" />';
    $content = $content.'<h1 id="provider-name">'.$post->post_title.'</h1>';
    $content = $content.'<p id="provider-address">'.$custom_fields["wpcf-direccion"][0].'</p>';
    $content = $content.'<p id="provider-phone">'.$custom_fields["wpcf-phone"][0].'</p>';
    $content = $content.'<p id="provider-facebook">'.$custom_fields["wpcf-facebook"][0].'</p>';

    return $content;
}
```

So, then when I request the info via browser, this is an example http://bride2be.com.mx/ceremonia/ the custom fields are displayed well, but when I request the JSON data only shows the HTML without the values of the custom fields.

**Here iss an example:**

http://bride2be.com.mx/wp-json.php/posts?type=ceremonia

I am little lost with this, someone can help me?

Comment: Scan the plugin for hooks, haven't looked much, but this one may help: `apply_filters( 'json_prepare_{$this->type}', $_post, $post, $context );`

Comment: I found this in the plugin code 'content' => apply_filters( 'the_content', $post['post_content'] ), so I think that the plugin implements that filter.

Comment: I don't have the plugin installed to help more... Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-do-you-debug-plugins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're using `the_content` filter is being applied **everywhere**, not only in the JSON API call.

Anyway, you should try to add a hook to the plugin, not to WordPress (at least, not at the first try).

The following is untested, but I believe is the right track:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Modify JSON for CPT */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'add_filter_so_19646036' );

# Load at a safe point
function add_filter_so_19646036()
{
    add_filter( 'json_prepare_post', 'apply_filter_so_19646036', 10, 3 );
}

function apply_filter_so_19646036( $_post, $post, $context )
{
    # Just a guess
    if( 'my_custom_type' === $post['post_type'] )
        $_post['content'] = 'my json content';

    # Brute force debug
    // var_dump( $_post );
    // var_dump( $post );
    // var_dump( $context );
    // die();

    return $_post;
}
```

You'd have to [inspect all three parameters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-do-you-debug-plugins) to make sure this will happen in the correct post types and that you're manipulating `$_post` correctly.

Comment: Thaks a lot, that works perfect :), last question, Where did you find documentation for json_prepare_post filter?

Comment: [Digging into the source](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html). A decent code editor; do a global search for `apply_filters` (or `do_action`); find a suspect for what we want; write a custom hook. Worked at first shot! Ye, I'm starting to get good at this ;)